# Video recording codec/muxer pack

Tags: c++, codec, video-recording, muxer

We are developing a multimedia application and we need an ability to save video recording from webcam to the hard drive. Currently, we are using [WebM VP8 codec](http://www.webmproject.org/) and muxer DShow filters.

We want to add ability to save recording in different containers like mkv, avi, mp4(may be) etc. I think we should also think of licensing H.264 AVC codec because we are going to implement Flash Media Server streaming within the app.

I guess we should consider purchasing some kind of Media Recording SDK. But all these licensing issues is a totally pain in the ass.

Can you advice something? May be someone of you already faced such task and successfully purchased something or found an opensource solution?

Please, share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance,

Anton

Comment: I can tell you that this will be a massive pain in the arse for the following reasons Gstreamer which is one of the most popular open source frameworks is very difficult to get up and running, the new Media foundation does not support natively writing video to avi containers but has good support for h264 but only works for vista and Win 7, using DS is a pain but it is mature and once you written one filter for a particular container they are all pretty much the same so I would use DShow as it is the most stable

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok, I will use DShow, but the question still remains. e.g. I want to buy DirectShow H.264 encoder - where to go? I cannot find any vendors/companies that will sell me such encoder (explain royalties etc)

Comment: You can use FFShow: http://www.free-codecs.com/download/ffdshow.htm there are also other free ones you can search for, the royalties will depend on the licence terms of the filter authors, what you want ideally is a full suite of filters, container unwrappers for mp4, mkv, m4v, decoder/encoders, muxers and splitters, and finally wrappers. Once you install some of these filters you can build filter graphs using http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/ just to test that your filter graph you will build programmatically will work

Comment: Also good discussion regarding h264 on msdn forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/6faf85ed-472a-4975-89f8-c933624642ed